# Change color of div and remove text of span using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<td class="tdLeftZoneCss" id="tdLeftZone">
<div>
<div style="border-bottom-color: black;">
<span>John</span>
```

1) I want to change color (black to #F2F2F2) of 2nd Div

2) I want to remove text ('John') written in span

How to do that using Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code,

```
$('.tdLeftZoneCss span').text('').parent().css('border-bottom-color','#F2F2F2');
```

Comment: if there are many span inside div then how to get first span ?

Comment: @Yogesh: try this, `$('.tdLeftZoneCss span').eq(0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tdLeftZone > div > div')               // find inner div
   .css('border-bottom-color', '#f2f2f2')  // change its style
   .children('span:first')                 // then find the first span
   .empty();                               // and erase its contents
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tdLeftZone div div ").css('color','#f2f2f2').children('span:first').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try this.. 
playing your JQuery as parent and child, remove & change ..

```
<div id="Destination"> 
    <div class="child_content"> item destination 1 </div>
    <div class="child_content"> item destination 2 </div>
</div>

    <div id="Source"> 
    <div class="child_content"> item source 1 </div>
    <div class="child_content"> item source 2 </div>
</div>

      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Source .child_content").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $(this).appendTo("#Destination");
                $(this).parent().css({"background":"black","color":"white"});
            });
        });
    </script>
```